# Is there a better way to re-write this method in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have this code that I wrote to parse a String that looks like a board of integers. Something like this:

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
3 4 5 2 3
1 2 4 5 1
4 6 2 7 3

The code is:

```
type Cell = (i32, bool);

struct Board {
    cells: Vec<Cell>,
}

impl Board {
    /// The input to this method is a string consisting of BOARD_WIDTH x BOARD_HEIGHT grid in a String.
    fn new(input: String) -> Board {
        let cells: Vec<Cell> = input
            .lines()
            .map(|s| {
                s.split_whitespace()
                    .map(|c| {
                        let cell_num: i32 = c.parse().unwrap();
                        return (cell_num, false);
                    })
                    .collect()
            })
            .collect::<Vec<Vec<Cell>>>()
            .into_iter()
            .flatten()
            .collect();
        return Board { cells };
    }
}
```

I am new to Rust so I am wondering if there is a better way to re-write this. I had a first iteration that looked like this:

```
let cells: Vec<Cell> = input
    .lines()
    .map(|s| {
        s.split_whitespace()
            .map(|c| {
                let cell_num: i32 = c.parse().unwrap();
                return (cell_num, false);
            })
    })
    .collect();
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: SO is for problem in code, you asking for code style advice, that off topic here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Comment: I was asking for a re-write of the code, not a style advice. I think this should be allowed, right? The answer below is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: nope same thing, you are more looking for code review stack exchange, that said your question is not bad, just off topic so don't worry about it. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Alright that makes sense! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
let cells: Vec<Cell> = input
    .lines()
    .flat_map(|s| {
        s
          .split_whitespace()
          .map(|c| {
                let cell_num: i32 = c.parse().unwrap();
                (cell_num, false)
           })
    })
    .collect();
```

Comment: Awesome!. Thanks for this :) Did not think of using flat_map.